# Entity reference by Feeds GUID

Tags: entities, feeds

Here's the scenario:

I have two feeds importers: Members Importer, which does the mapping

```
SOURCE      TARGET                         TARGET CONFIGURATION
id          GUID (guid)                    Used as unique
id          member_id (field_member_id)    Used as unique
first_name  First Name (field_first_name)
last_name   Last Name (field_last_name)
```

and Bigs Importer, which does the mapping

```
SOURCE          TARGET                               TARGET CONFIGURATION
from_member_id  member_id (field_member_id)          Used as unique
to_member_id    Big Brother(s) (Entity reference by 
                Feeds GUID) (field_big_brother_s_)
```

Both have Bundle set to the custom content type `Member`; note that `field_big_brother_s_` is an entity reference to a node which is also of content type Member, which is why I need two separate importers.

#### Questions:

(For ease of discussions, I've appended a couple example sources to the end of this post.)

1. Can I guarantee that running Bigs Import on the source below (after running Members Importer on the other source) will add `The Doctor` to `Mr. Rogers`'s `Big Brother(s)` field? I've read that GUID is only guaranteed to be unique for a single import, or something like that.
2. If the answer to 1. is no, is it possible to do the entity reference lookup by the `member_id` field and eliminate GUID stuff entirely?

#### Example Sources:

Source for Members Importer:

```
id,first_name,last_name
1 ,Bob       ,Dylan    
2 ,Mister    ,Rogers   
3 ,The       ,Doctor
```

Source for Bigs Importer:

```
id,from_member_id,to_member_id
1 ,2             ,3
2 ,1             ,3
2 ,1             ,2
```